# Folding in (estimating topics for new documents) in LDA using Mallet in Java

Tags: java, mallet, topic-modeling

I'm using Mallet through Java, and I can't work out how to evaluate new documents against an existing topic model which I have trained.

My initial code to generate my model is very similar to that in the [Mallett Developers Guide for Topic Modelling](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/topics-devel.php), after which I simply save the model as a Java object. In a later process, I reload that Java object from file, add new instances via `.addInstances()` and would then like to evaluate only these new instances against the topics found in the original training set.

[This stats.SE thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9315/topic-prediction-using-latent-dirichlet-allocation) provides some high-level suggestions, but I can't see how to work them into the Mallet framework.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And I've found the answer hidden in a [slide-deck from Mallet's lead developer](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/mallet-tutorial.pdf):

```
TopicInferencer inferencer = model.getInferencer();
double[] topicProbs = inferencer.getSampledDistribution(newInstance, 100, 10, 10);
```

Comment: This is the way to go. Also, If you want to save the model after training and load it before testing (to keep them separate) you could take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44379106/1042409

Answer (score 5):

Inference is actually also listed in the [example link](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/topics-devel.php) provided in the question (the last few lines).

For anyone interested in the whole code for saving/loading the trained model and then using it for inferring model distribution for new documents - here are some snippets:

After `model.estimate()` has completed, you have the actual trained model so you can serialize it using a standard Java `ObjectOutputStream` (since `ParallelTopicModel` implements `Serializable`):

```
try {
    FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream("model.ser");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(outFile);
    oos.writeObject(model);
    oos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    // handle this error
} catch (IOException ex) {
    // handle this error
}
```

Note though, when you infer, you need also to pass the new sentences (as `Instance`) through the same pipeline in order to pre-process it (tokenzie etc) thus, you need to also save the pipe-list (since we're using `SerialPipe` when can create an instance and then serialize it):

```
// initialize the pipelist (using in model training)
SerialPipes pipes = new SerialPipes(pipeList);

try {
    FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream("pipes.ser");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(outFile);
    oos.writeObject(pipes);
    oos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    // handle error
} catch (IOException ex) {
    // handle error
}
```

In order to load the model/pipeline and use them for inference we need to de-serialize:

```
private static void InferByModel(String sentence) {
    // define model and pipeline
    ParallelTopicModel model = null;
    SerialPipes pipes = null;

    // load the model
    try {
        FileInputStream outFile = new FileInputStream("model.ser");
        ObjectInputStream oos = new ObjectInputStream(outFile);
        model = (ParallelTopicModel) oos.readObject();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Could not read model from file: " + ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Could not load the model: " + ex);
    }

    // load the pipeline
    try {
        FileInputStream outFile = new FileInputStream("pipes.ser");
        ObjectInputStream oos = new ObjectInputStream(outFile);
        pipes = (SerialPipes) oos.readObject();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Could not read pipes from file: " + ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Could not load the pipes: " + ex);
    }

    // if both are properly loaded
    if (model != null && pipes != null){

        // Create a new instance named "test instance" with empty target 
        // and source fields note we are using the pipes list here
        InstanceList testing = new InstanceList(pipes);   
        testing.addThruPipe(
            new Instance(sentence, null, "test instance", null));

        // here we get an inferencer from our loaded model and use it
        TopicInferencer inferencer = model.getInferencer();
        double[] testProbabilities = inferencer
                   .getSampledDistribution(testing.get(0), 10, 1, 5);
        System.out.println("0\t" + testProbabilities[0]);
    }
}
```

For some reason I am not getting the exact same inference with the loaded model as with the original one - but this is a matter for another question (if anyone knows though, I'd be happy to hear)

Comment: In order to get the same result after consecutive inferences you just have to add inferencer.setRandomSeed(1). However, if I use the inferencer for a text document I've already used in the model, I cannot get the same topic distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the useful code snippets. But performance-wise it would be better to directly generete an inferencer while training the model instead of first loading the whole model and then getting the inferencer from it.

Comment: @Phauly - sometimes you want to train a model and then use it later on. In that case, if makes sense to train the model and then save it to be used for inference whenever necessary (if I understood your comment)