# Different topic distributions for the same data with mallet topic modeling

Tags: java, topic-modeling, mallet

I am using `Mallet topic modeling` and I have trained a model. Right after the training, I print the topic distribution for one of the documents of the training set and save it. Then, I try the same document as the test set and pass it through the same pipes and so on. But I get a completely different topic distribution for that. The highest ranked topic after the training which as a probability of around 0.54, has a probability of 0.000 when used as the test set. Here are my codes for the training and testing:

```
 public static ArrayList<Object> trainModel() throws IOException {

        String fileName = "E:\\Alltogether.txt";
        String stopwords = "E:\\stopwords-en.txt";
        // Begin by importing documents from text to feature sequences
        ArrayList<Pipe> pipeList = new ArrayList<Pipe>();

        // Pipes: lowercase, tokenize, remove stopwords, map to features
        pipeList.add(new CharSequenceLowercase());
        pipeList.add(new CharSequence2TokenSequence(Pattern.compile("\\p{L}[\\p{L}\\p{P}]+\\p{L}")));
        pipeList.add(new TokenSequenceRemoveStopwords(new File(stopwords), "UTF-8", false, false, false));
        pipeList.add(new TokenSequenceRemoveNonAlpha(true));
        pipeList.add(new TokenSequence2FeatureSequence());
        InstanceList instances = new InstanceList(new SerialPipes(pipeList));

        Reader fileReader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(fileName)), "UTF-8");
        instances.addThruPipe(new CsvIterator(fileReader, Pattern.compile("^(\\S*)[\\s,]*(\\S*)[\\s,]*(.*)$"),
                3, 2, 1)); // data, label, name fields

        int numTopics = 75;
        ParallelTopicModel model = new ParallelTopicModel(numTopics, 5.0, 0.01);

        model.setOptimizeInterval(20);
        model.addInstances(instances);
        model.setNumThreads(2);
        model.setNumIterations(2000);
        model.estimate();

        ArrayList<Object> results = new ArrayList<>();
        results.add(model);
        results.add(instances);

        Alphabet dataAlphabet = instances.getDataAlphabet();

        FeatureSequence tokens = (FeatureSequence) model.getData().get(66).instance.getData();
        LabelSequence topics = model.getData().get(66).topicSequence;

        Formatter out = new Formatter(new StringBuilder(), Locale.US);
        for (int position = 0; position < tokens.getLength(); position++) {
            out.format("%s-%d ", dataAlphabet.lookupObject(tokens.getIndexAtPosition(position)), topics.getIndexAtPosition(position));
        }
        System.out.println(out);

        // Estimate the topic distribution of the 66th instance,
        //  given the current Gibbs state.
        double[] topicDistribution = model.getTopicProbabilities(66);

        ArrayList<TreeSet<IDSorter>> topicSortedWords = model.getSortedWords();

        for (int topic = 0; topic < numTopics; topic++) {
            Iterator<IDSorter> iterator = topicSortedWords.get(topic).iterator();

            out = new Formatter(new StringBuilder(), Locale.US);
            out.format("%d\t%.3f\t", topic, topicDistribution[topic]);
            int rank = 0;
            while (iterator.hasNext() && rank < 10) {
                IDSorter idCountPair = iterator.next();
                out.format("%s (%.0f) ", dataAlphabet.lookupObject(idCountPair.getID()), idCountPair.getWeight());
                rank++;
            }
            System.out.println(out);
        }

        return results;
    }
```

And here is the testing part:

```
private static void testModel(ArrayList<Object> results, String testDir) {


    ParallelTopicModel model = (ParallelTopicModel) results.get(0);
    InstanceList allTrainInstances = (InstanceList) results.get(1);

    String stopwords = "E:\\stopwords-en.txt";

    ArrayList<Pipe> pipeList = new ArrayList<Pipe>();

    pipeList.add(new CharSequenceLowercase());
    pipeList.add(new CharSequence2TokenSequence(Pattern.compile("\\p{L}[\\p{L}\\p{P}]+\\p{L}")));
    pipeList.add(new TokenSequenceRemoveStopwords(new File(stopwords), "UTF-8", false, false, false));
    pipeList.add(new TokenSequenceRemoveNonAlpha(true));
    pipeList.add(new TokenSequence2FeatureSequence());

    InstanceList instances = new InstanceList(new SerialPipes(pipeList));

    Reader fileReader = null;
    try {
        fileReader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(testDir)), "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    instances.addThruPipe(new CsvIterator(fileReader, Pattern.compile("^(\\S*)[\\s,]*(\\S*)[\\s,]*(.*)$"),
            3, 2, 1)); // data, label, name fields

    TopicInferencer inferencer = model.getInferencer();
    inferencer.setRandomSeed(1);

    double[] testProbabilities = inferencer.getSampledDistribution(instances.get(0), 10, 1, 5);
    System.out.println(testProbabilities);
    int index = getMaximum(testProbabilities);

    ArrayList<TreeSet<IDSorter>> topicSortedWords = model.getSortedWords();

    Alphabet dataAlphabet = allTrainInstances.getDataAlphabet();
    Formatter out = new Formatter(new StringBuilder(), Locale.US);

    for (int topic = 0; topic < 75; topic++) {
        Iterator<IDSorter> iterator = topicSortedWords.get(topic).iterator();

        out = new Formatter(new StringBuilder(), Locale.US);
        out.format("%d\t%.3f\t", topic, testProbabilities[topic]);
        int rank = 0;
        while (iterator.hasNext() && rank < 10) {
            IDSorter idCountPair = iterator.next();
            out.format("%s (%.0f) ", dataAlphabet.lookupObject(idCountPair.getID()), idCountPair.getWeight());
            rank++;
        }
        System.out.println(out);
    }

}
```

In the line

```
    double[] testProbabilities = inferencer.getSampledDistribution(instances.get(0), 10, 1, 5);
```

I can simply see that the probabilities are different. In the meantime, I have tried with different files, but I always get the same topic as the highest ranked topic. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my own question for later uses if somebody faces the same problem.
In the documents of `MALLET` it's said that you should use the same pipes for training and testing.
I realized that "new"ing the same pipes as done for the training step does **NOT** mean using the same pipes. You should save the pipes when you train your model and re-load the them when testing. I took the sample code for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141195/folding-in-estimating-topics-for-new-documents-in-lda-using-mallet-in-java) and it works now.